# serializing JSON files with newlines in Python

Tags: python, json, serialization, pickle, jsonpickle

I am using json and jsonpickle sometimes to serialize objects to files, using the following function:

```
def json_serialize(obj, filename, use_jsonpickle=True):
    f = open(filename, 'w')
    if use_jsonpickle:
    import jsonpickle
    json_obj = jsonpickle.encode(obj)
    f.write(json_obj)
    else:
    simplejson.dump(obj, f) 
    f.close()
```

The problem is that if I serialize a dictionary for example, using "json_serialize(mydict, myfilename)" then the entire serialization gets put on one line.  This means that I can't grep the file for entries to be inspected by hand, like I would a CSV file. Is there a way to make it so each element of an object (e.g. each entry in a dict, or each element in a list) is placed on a separate line in the JSON output file?

thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Jsonpickle uses one of the json backends and so you can try this to your code:

```
jsonpickle.set_encoder_options('simplejson', sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Update: simplejson has been incorporated into base python, just replace `simplejson` for `json` and you'll get the pretty-printed/formatted/non-minified json

```
jsonpickle.set_encoder_options('json', sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 5):

`(simple)json.dump()` has the `indent` argument. `jsonpickle` probably has something similar, or in the worst case you can decode it and encode it again.